# Display is dim after updating graphics driver

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

**Tad bit of summary:**
So I have had the "pleasure" of owning an HP laptop for a few years now. Since HP does not update their drivers for a long time I was stuck with AMD 8.3 drivers. I recently updated to 13.3 in a different way (as HP was not letting me update via AMD). Everything went fine, except the backlight to my display is very dim/not on at all, and the options in the control panel will not raise or lower my brightness.

**Question:**
Is there anyway I can manually with some other application/script control my backlight brightness other than going back to 8.3(which is not in the question seeing as though most modern apps crash your computer with 8.3)

**Laptop Specs:**
*OS:* Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
*Graphics Driver:* 13.200.0.0
*Graphics Card:* AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series
*Laptop:* HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC

Comment: I think the problem is unrelated and is actually the [inverter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hp+dv7+inverter&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ahp+dv7+inverter).  Back in college - my buddy and I fixed about 8 of these with the same symptoms.  It's a cheap part and easy to fix (just take off the screen bezel with 4-6 screws and it's at the bottom)

Comment: @nerdwaller The thing is I updated the drivers about 1 hour ago, and it broke literally right as the new driver was installed, and it was working before hand. Thus it is a software problem.

Comment: Heard that many times before...  But to verify, then I would suggest rolling back (just to make sure that's for sure the issue) before chasing it.  Just my opinion from seeing this exact situation before (usually on dv2k's) - and that being the issue (amazingly timed every time).

Comment: @nerdwaller I will load it back, it sounds like some sort of powersurge might happen when updating that brakes the inverter.

Comment: @nerdwaller I just updated the driver for my graphics card via windows. That seamed to do the trick.